# Does ping 127.0.0.1 test the status of my wifi card?

Tags: wireless, ping

My Wifi does not work anymore and the command `lspci` is not showing any wireless card.
The device is not either listed under `lshw -C`. The `dmesg` command does not give any clue about errors with wifi.
So I am wondering if there is any command that can show if at least the wifi card is intact or broken? I thought first about `ping 127.0.0.1`, which shows a response without error, but I am confused from the documentation if this ping command is really showing if the wifi card is intact or something else. Is there any other command that tests if the card is intact apart from the drivers etc that are installed?

Comment: You did test already: That's what `lshw` did. If detected-but-unrecognized, then it would be a kernel/driver/firmware problem. No hardware detected at all means that it's dead or physically disconnected.

Comment: @user535733: thank you. So the best would be to open the laptop and see if the wifi card is disconnected?

Comment: Wireless cards don't magically disconnect. They do, however, occasionally die. Opening the case is up to you; simply consider if what you are likely to learn is useful on the path to your goal, and if the effort expended will be worthwhile. It may be more worthwhile to keep the laptop case closed and invest in a new USB wireless dongle.

Comment: Indeed, I was thinking about the possibility of a USB wireless dongle. Any advice regarding type / brand of dongle, that is compatible with Linux, and possibility to upgrade? (currently I am running Ubuntu 18).

Answer (score 1):

Just to answer the original question: no, `ping 127.0.0.1` will not test a wifi card, or any other hardware network interface for that matter. All Linux machines have a localhost network interface, which exists just in software and does not correspond to some hardware. `ping 127.0.0.1` will send an ICMP 'echo request' packet to the localhost network interface, and the software will respond with an ICMP 'echo reply' packet.

If the wifi card is broken, you can try to replace it. In recent laptops that I've opened, its a separate card using a Mini PCIe slot. The cards are either full-height or half-height. See [here](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-upgrade-your-laptops-wi-fi-card/) for example.